# How to enter images in mysql using php as interface?

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to enter image in mysql database but not able to insert images in database.
so, any one help me how to insert images in database so that i can use that images in my web page by fetching it through php code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please insert your code and give database details with field description of table. and see the link of Fred -ii's for doing better question

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to add image into database:

1. Save image as binary object into your table (bad option in the vast number of cases)
2. Save image somewhere else (for example into server filesystem) and just add path to image into your table (good option)

Answer (score 0):

You could ad it as a BLOB. I never did that.
But I rather store the src-link in some way to your DB and upload the image via FTP or PHP to a directory.

Then call it in your page as img

To be clear: store this in your db and put it in your HTML while the page is loading:

```
<div class="myimage"><img src="imagedir/myimage.jpg" alt="myimage"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting image is not a good idea because:

- read/write to a Database is always slower than a filesystem
- Your Database backups grow to be huge and more time consuming. It also put Heavy load on the database server.
- Require additional code to extract and stream the images
- Web servers, need special coding or processing to access images in the file system

you can try to upload the image in the server using move_upload_file function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: check this link http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/upload%20image%20to%20database%20and%20server%20using%20HTML,PHP%20and%20MySQL.php